# JavaScript - wait for a function to finish processing before going to the next iteration of the loop

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, wait

I would like to make one function wait for another to finish completely. We have this function that processes a list of files and loads each one of them into the loadFileIntoMemory function.

I would like this function to wait for the loadFileIntoMemory function to finish manipulating and working on said file before going to the next iteration of the loop and calling it with the next file.

```
function processFiles(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log("Loading File into memory");
    loadFileIntoMemory(files[i]);
  }
}
```

So it would load file number 1, wait for everything to be done and over, then load file 2. I don't want it to spam files at the loadFileIntoMemory function without it finishing the previous file.

```
function loadFileIntoMemory(file) {
  
  //create a dictionary using the file name
  originalValues[file.name] = {};
  // create a variable with the file name to pass to storeOriginalValues and replaceOccurence
  var filename = file.name;
  // Start reading the file
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (file) {
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    // Here we have the file data as an ArrayBuffer.  dicomParser requires as input a
    // Uint8Array so we create that here
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    dataSet = dicomParser.parseDicom(byteArray);
    // Store the original values into the dict
    storeOriginalValues(filename);

    // iterate through each metadata field and replace the original value with the de-identified value.
    console.log("De-identifying values")

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(elementsToRemove)) {
      var element = dataSet.elements[value];
      if (typeof element !== "undefined") {
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          dataSet.byteArray[element.dataOffset + i] = 32;
        }
      }
    }

    // Check if the Patient ID is still Present after the de-indentification process is completed
    replaceOccurences(filename, originalValues[filename].PatientID);
    // replaceOccurences(filename, originalValues[filename].PatientName);
    // replaceOccurences(filename, originalValues[filename].etc);

    // download the de-identified DICOM P10 bytestream
    console.log('Downloading File');
    var blob = new Blob([dataSet.byteArray], { type: "application/dicom" });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: You should make `loadFileIntoMemory` async then.  `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { ... all the rest of your code here ... })` and call `resolve` when the `reader.onload` completes its processing.

Comment: maybe. I posted a question two days ago and got obliterated.

Comment: There are actually tons of tutorials on asynchronous programming with javascript. Work through some of them and adapt your code accordingly. If after that still something doesn't work come back here

Comment: ...of course, `processFiles` will have to become async too, and you'll then `await` each `loadFileIntoMemory`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert your loadFileIntoMemory into a Promise.

```
function loadFileIntoMemory(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
        ......
        reader.onload = function (file) {
           ......
           return resolve();  //when all is done, resolve the promise.
        }

    })
}
```

Then you can use the function in a async/await loop.

```
const processFiles = async (files) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log("Loading File into memory");
    await loadFileIntoMemory(files[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have followed this exactly, but now I'm getting: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: resolve is not defined

Comment: i have a typo where `new Promise` is declared. I've made the ammendment

Comment: you are a real g, thanks boss

Comment: Note that [MDN recommends wrapping callback functions at the lowest possible level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api). This would mean introducing an additional function. However you're then able to simplify `loadFileIntoMemory`. Here is an example with the given code https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/77c7cf159814a9bb92cbd97cdb9f966c